# How do use a method pointer as a parameter of another method?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters, void-pointers

I've searched all over for a solution to this, it might just be I don't know how to properly put it into words.

I want this `firstFunction` to call the `otherFunction` when it's address is declared in `firstFunction`'s parameters.

This is my code:

**init.h**:

```
class Ainit
{
  //function to be passed into firstFunction
  void test();
  void firstFunction( void (Ainit::*otherFunction)() );  
};
```

**init.cpp**:

```
void Ainit::firstFunction( void (Ainit::*otherFunction)() )
{
    (Ainit::*otherFunction)();
}
```

Xcode: points at the `*` in the following line with the Error: `Expected unqualified-id`

```
(Ainit::*otherFunction)();
```

How do I invoke the method I pass to `firstFunction` within `firstFunction`?

Comment: How do you imagine you can use a pointer-to-member-function without an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
(this->*otherFunction)();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the Ainit:: when declaring the parameter of firstFunction and when you are calling the *otherFunction. The following code does just fine:

```
class Ainit { 

void test();

void firstFunction (void * otherFunction());
};

void Ainit::test() {
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

void Ainit::firstFunction(void * otherFunction()) {
(*otherFunction)();
}
```